# Probability : Container arrangement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

There are a total of 15 containers out of which two containers have same color and the remaining are of different colors. The question is to find the probability that

i) Two containers with same color are always together.

ii) They(containers with same color) are never together.

**My answers :**

i) Total Number of ways 15 containers can be arranged = 15! ways

Considering 2 containers with same color as a single color

Now total number of ways to arrange 2 container  = 14!

P(The containers with same color are always together) = 14!/15! 1/15

ii) P(Containers with same color are never together ) (13!*2!)/(25!) = 1/300

But i'm sure that the second one is not correct.Please help me solve the problem.

**Corrected Answer**

i) P(The containers with same color are always together) = $\frac{2}{15}$

ii) P(The containers with same color are never together = $1  - \frac{2}{15}$ 
= $\frac{13}{15}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that the $15$ containers are arranged at random in a *line*, with all arrangement equally likely. (The analysis would be a little different if the containers are arranged in a *circle*.)

For the first question, if we use your method, we need to imagine that the two blue containers are subtly different. (Say they have ID numbers.) For the number of arrangements in which the blues are together, first tie them together. Then we have $14$ objects, which can be arranged in $14!$ ways. Now untie them. There are $2$ orders in which the blues can be put. So the number of "favourables" is $2\cdot 14!$, and the probability is $\frac{2}{15}$.

The answer to the second problem is $1$ minus the answer to the first. For the event "the two blues are not together" is the complement of the event "the two blues are together."

**Remark:** We mention another way to solve the first problem. We can **choose** the set of positions for the blues in $\binom{15}{2}$ equally likely ways. Of these choices, $14$ have the two blues next to each other, so our probability is $\frac{14}{\binom{15}{2}}$.
This simplifies to $\frac{2}{15}$.

Comment: You are welcome. Your method for the first problem was fine, except that the two blues can be together in two ways, Blue 1 before Blue 2, and the other way.